# standalone instructions work but they don't work inside a function

Tags: python, ipython

I am sorry if my question is for newbie, but I think it's very very strange.
I have the following piece of code:

```
import apt_pkg
import apt

pkg="linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic"
p=apt.progress.text.AcquireProgress()
c=apt.Cache()
u=c[pkg].candidate.uri
a=apt_pkg.Acquire(p)
apt_pkg.AcquireFile(a,uri=u)
a.run()
```

On iPython it works, outside iPython it does not work.

From iPyhton:

```
In [3]: pkg="linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic"

In [4]: c=apt.Cache()
u=c[pkg].candidate.uri

In [5]: u=c[pkg].candidate.uri

In [6]: p=apt.progress.text.AcquireProgress()

In [7]: a=apt_pkg.Acquire(p)

In [8]: apt_pkg.AcquireFile(a,uri=u)
Out[8]: <apt_pkg.AcquireFile object:Status: 0 Complete: 0 Local: 0 IsTrusted: 0 FileSize: 0 DestFile:'linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic_4.4.0-116.140_i386.deb' DescURI: 'http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic_4.4.0-116.140_i386.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>

In [9]: a.run()
Get:1  [20.7 MB]                                                                                                                                            
Fetched 20.7 MB in 6s (1643 kB/s)                                                                                                                           
Out[9]: 0
```

from shell:

```
myuser@mypc:~/github/mycode$ ./aptciao.py 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
```